# AJAX/jQuery sending front end user input as NULL to MYSQL upon submission. Any fix? (SpringMVC, Eclipse, JSP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC in Eclipse to create a ToDo List. And all things added in ToDo (from user Input), are going to a MYSQL database column by using AJAX/jQuery. The code below is on a JSP File.

However, it is adding a row, but is being sent as NULL.

Can anyone teach me why it is sending as NULL and what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

```
      <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
        
        
        
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <p><a class='btn' href="#add" rel="modal:open">Add New Company</a></p>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
        <div id="myDIV" class="header" >
          <h2 style="margin:5px">To Do List</h2>
          
            <form id="add" action="#" class="add_form modal" > 
          <input type="text" id="myInput" name="name" placeholder="Title...">      
          <span id = "addNew"  onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
         </form>
        </div>
         
        <ul id="myUL" class="list1">
         
        </ul>
        
        </div>
        
        <div id='msg'/>
        
        
            
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
         
    
    function newElement() {
           
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      var ulist = document.getElementById("myUL");
      var newItem = document.createElement("li");
      var yoube = document.getElementById('myInput');

      a.textContent = yoube.value;
      a.setAttribute('href', yoube.value);
      newItem.appendChild(a);
      ulist.appendChild(newItem);
         
      $(document).delegate('#addNew', 'click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var name = $('#name').val();
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/company/save",
                data: JSON.stringify({'VARIABLEXYZ': name}),
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert("Hello! This went wrong");            }
            });
        });
      
    }
    
        
        </script>
        
      
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var name = $("input[name='name']")`
to select all input items where the name is "name".

You also probably have to write a function to manage how each value is sent. For example,

```
    let json_data = {}
    name.each(function(index) {
        json_data[index] = this.value
    });
```

Comment: Did not work out unfortunately. I went ahead and removed the second user input box and everything related to it, for sake of simplicity when anyone reads this.

Comment: type console.log(index, this.value) under the json_data[index] = this.value line and reply what it shows on your console